# How to reattempt to pay a subscription that payment method failed with another payment method?

Tags: stripe-payments, expo

I'm using stripe to subscribe, so I have this issue.

When I subscribe and the card does not have sufficient funds, the subscription object is created
So my question is how can I reattempt to pay the subscription that I just created.

I am guiding from this example:
https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/fixed-price

Here is a photo of the function that is supposed to do the retry, but all it does is change the user's default card.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's described further down that document, right here: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/fixed-price#manage-subscription-payment-failure

Comment: Yes, I'm reading that document, but they don't say how to reattempt the payment 
Using their method, I just change the default payment method

Comment: The next section down describes how to do it, both on the frontend and backend.